# PhpStorm doesn't recognize installed pecl_http

Tags: php, phpstorm, pecl

I've installed php 5.6 using homebrew:

```
brew install php56 --with-pear
```

I've also installed pecl_http:

```
sudo pecl install pecl_http-2.5.5
```

I've configured the php interpreter (see image showing the configuration, as well as the opening lines of my php.ini file, which shows that the http extension has been installed).

[image]

When I attempt to run my application, I get the following error message:

[image]

```
Fatal error: Class 'HTTPRequest' not found in ...
```

**What else needs to happen for the interpreter to find the pecl_http extension?**

Comment: Click on `(i)` icon (after "refresh" icon) on your first screenshot and see if that extension is actually loaded. Thing is: in your `php.ini` you have placed those 3 lines with extensions way too early -- better place them in the same place where "native" extensions are located (just after them). AFAIK they have to belong to "PHP" section but if they placed like this they will be outside of any section.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with PHPStorm. The class HttpRequest is provided by **v1** of this PECL extension.

Re-install via: `$ pecl install -f pecl_http-1.7.6`

You can find documentation for **v2** here, though:
https://mdref.m6w6.name/http

Comment: Hmm, installing version 1.7.6 fails because of compilation errors... Stuff like this: /private/var/folders/3f/gq2hw09942q6w3vpmgh6k_zc0000gn/T/pear/temp/pecl_http/http_api.c:403:23: error: no member named 'raw_post_data' in 'sapi_request_info'
        if (SG(request_info).raw_post_data) {
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
6 errors generated.
make: *** [http_api.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed